# Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in Paypal payment for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, paypal

I try to get the transaction detail base on Paypal Sdk when user confirm to pay. However, encountered problem for the code below

**problem encountered:**

Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in

fun<T :[ERROR:(name:String) :T!] > getParcelableExtra please specify it explicitly

for this line:  val confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION)

and  not sure what this means toString(4):
val paymentDetails = confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4)

Thanks

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent?) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(requestCode == my_request_code){

         
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

             
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                   
                    val confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION)

                    if (confirm != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Getting the payment details
                            val paymentDetails = confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4)

      
                        // Log.i("paymentExample", paymentDetails)
                        //Starting a new activity for the payment details and also putting the payment details with intent
                           
                            startActivity(Intent(this, ConfirmationActivity::class.java)
                                .putExtra("PaymentDetails", paymentDetails)
                                .putExtra("PaymentAmount", paymentAmount))
                        }
                        catch (e: JSONException) {
                            Log.e("paymentExample", "an extremely unlikely failure occurred: ", e)
                        }
                   }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and not sure what this means toString(4):
> val paymentDetails = confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4)

This should really be a separate question but it's [a method on `JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#toString(int)):

> `public String toString (int indentSpaces)`
>
> Encodes this object as a human readable JSON string for debugging

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you convert data from Parcelable you must specify in which object you need to convert.

As per the document if class is `PaymentConfirmation`than you have to specify like this:

```
val confirm: PaymentConfirmation = data?.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION)
```

Comment: can u tell me what is toString(4) means confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4)   . thanks